# iPad View does not transfer to iPad correctly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, view

I have an XIB with two iPad views (one portrait, one landscape). I have about 7 buttons on each, which fill up the entire view when I'm in the Xcode XIB builder. I have selected my views to be "iPad" on simulated metrics. However, when I run the simulator, or send the app to my device, my buttons appear very small, and only take up the corner of the iPad.

I've seen issues with other people and the view, but none of them are this specific issue.

I have another XIB file for the iPhone, and that works perfectly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check the Autosizing settings within InterfaceBuilder on the XIBs that work and on those that do not.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the two possibilities -

1. when u add the xib or the class with which that xib is added initially in xCode u check the option "iPad".If you did so then

2.Check in interface builder if you disturb the auto-resizing property then set it to default.

Comment: I did check off iPad, and my auto-resizing is set to default. Is there any other possibility?